# Typeorm joins no longer works after using an entity that extends from another entity

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have an entity that extends from another entity and I do so add a column to the original entity.

```
@Entity({ name: 'MarketInfo', schema: 'iris' })
export class newEntity extends oldEntity {
  @Column({
    type: 'jsonb',
  })
  geoJson: any;
}
```

I have a method that uses that newEntity:

```
export class MarketService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(HeliosMarketInfoEntity) private readonly repository: Repository<HeliosMarketInfoEntity>,
  ) {}

  getCustomerMarkets(requestCustomer: CustomerEntity, query?: CustomerMarketsDto): Promise<newEntity[]> {
      const isAdmin = requestCustomer.accountType !== AccountType.BASIC;

      const resultCustomerId = query?.customCustomerId || requestCustomer.customerId;
      return <Promise<MarketInfoEntity[]>>this.repository
        .createQueryBuilder('market')
        [isAdmin ? 'leftJoin' : 'innerJoin']('market.customers', 'customer')
        .where(isAdmin ? 'TRUE' : 'customer.customerId = :customerId', {
          customerId: resultCustomerId,
        })
        .orderBy('"marketName"', 'ASC')
        .getMany()
        .map((market) => pick(market, ['marketId', 'marketName', 'metaData', 'marketHash']));
   }
}
```

But it gives me this error when I called it:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tablePath')
```

Upon investigating I found that the error stems from the joins. But I don't have a clue what is the root cause.

I tried changing it back to oldEntity in getCustomerMarkets but I still have the same error. It's only when I revert back to the old repository in the constructor that everything, joins, and all work again.

This is Nest.js and the newEntity is imported correctly in the module. My `ormconfig` file also has newEntity.

Should I be using a different way to join?